# Bulk disable products without a category in SQL

Tags: sql

Can anyone provide me with a good SQL query I can run to disable products that have no category?

I have been trying to use extensions to do this and have yet to get a reliable program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right way to do it versus using a direct SQL query. Magento has event driven tasks that are performed when saving/updating a product. When running a direct SQL query, you skip all of those events and you run the risk of messing up your database in one way or another.

Here is the safest way to do this:

```
    $adapter   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $linkTable = $adapter->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
    $select    = $adapter->select()->from($linkTable, 'product_id');
    $select->distinct(true);
    $activeProductIds = $adapter->fetchCol($select);

    $model      = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $resource   = $model->getResource();
    $collection = $model->getCollection();

    // filter collection by products not in the active product ids array
    $collection->addFieldToFilter($resource->getIdFieldName(), array('nin' => $activeProductIds));

    // add filter to select only products currently enabled so that you don't waste time disabling products that are already disabled
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        $product->save();
    }
```

In response to your question of "where do I run this?", I will give you the quick and dirty way to do it. Please note that **I would normally recommend creating yourself a very small module with a button somewhere in the admin panel so that you can run this on demand** but teaching how to build a module is a bit too much for this post.

- Create a file in the root of your Magento site called disable.php or something like that. Whatever you want to call it really.
- Place the contents of the code below into it.
- Go to http://www.yourdomain.com/disable.php to run it
- If this is a production site, you will probably want to delete this file immediately after running it.

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

try {
    $adapter   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $linkTable = $adapter->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
    $select    = $adapter->select()->from($linkTable, 'product_id');
    $select->distinct(true);
    $activeProductIds = $adapter->fetchCol($select);

    $model      = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $resource   = $model->getResource();
    $collection = $model->getCollection();

    // filter collection by products not in the active product ids array
    $collection->addFieldToFilter($resource->getIdFieldName(), array('nin' => $activeProductIds));

    // add filter to select only products currently enabled so that you don't waste time disabling products that are already disabled
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        $product->save();
    }
    echo 'Products successfully disabled.';
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If you have an enormous number of products then the method above will timeout. Here is a much faster way to accomplish the same. The code below assumes that you either have only one store view or that you want this change applied for all store views.

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

try {

    $adapter   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $linkTable = $adapter->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
    $select    = $adapter->select()->from($linkTable, 'product_id');
    $select->distinct(true);
    $activeProductIds = $adapter->fetchCol($select);

    $model        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $resource     = $model->getResource();
    $attribute    = $resource->getAttribute('status');
    $attributeId  = $attribute->getId();
    $entityTypeId = $attribute->getEntityTypeId();
    $table        = $attribute->getBackendTable();

    $enabled  = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;
    $disabled = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED;

    $updated = $adapter->update($table, array('value' => $disabled), array(
        $adapter->quoteInto('attribute_id = ?', $attributeId),
        $adapter->quoteInto('entity_type_id = ?', $entityTypeId),
        $adapter->quoteInto('entity_id NOT IN(?)', $activeProductIds),
        $adapter->quoteInto('value = ?', $enabled)
    ));

    echo "{$updated} products successfully disabled.";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Where do I run this command?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you the easiest way. If it works for you please accept. I should note that I tested it out before I posted it.

Comment: You should always make a backup but this will not screw you up. I am a Certified Magento Developer, I do this full time for a living.

Comment: Just to explain whats happening: The first query simply reads from the database. It obtains the product IDs of all products assigned to a category. The second query pulls a product collection of all products that are not within the IDs from the first query and also filters out any products that are already disabled. Then, using Magento's native functionality, you disabled and save the products within the foreach loop.

Comment: Nothing happens.

I go to the URL and it simply displays the code to me. Then it does nothing.

Hmmm.

Comment: You have to put an opening php tag on the first line of the file. `<?php`. I tried to include it for you but the text editor seemed to ignore it here on the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39822/discussion-between-shawn-abramson-and-eric-conklin).

Answer (score 0):

Whats about a database query:
update `catalog_category_entity_int` set value=0 where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from `eav_attribute` where entity_type_id=3 and attribute_code='is_active') and entity_id not in (select distinct category_id from `catalog_category_product`)

Usefull if there are a lot of empty categories, but you should enable categories of higer level again (when these have no products attached)